# How to remove user defined line in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to remove specific lines entered by the user in one file then save this file same as the file name.

For example I have this code

```
for /f "tokens=2,3" %%a in ('type c:\files.txt') do 
(
    Set /p line= ENTER THE LINE YOU WANT TO DISREGARD:
    findstr /v /r /c:"^[!line!]*$" "c:\file1\%%a" > "c:\file2\%%a"      ----> For Column2 (Name1)
    findstr /v /r /c:"^[!line!]*$" "c:\file1\%%a" > "c:\file2\%%a"      ----> For Column3 (Name2) 
)
```

Files.txt contains filenames of other files. Then in my *for* statement, It opens all the files indicated in Files.txt (Column2 and Column3)

files.txt sample contents:

```
Name    Name1.txt   Name2.txt
Age     Age1.txt    Age2.txt
Add     Add1.txt    Add2.txt
```

Once I run the batch file,why it automatically deletes all the text inside the file?. Also, How can I delete multiple user defined in one prompt? Can I have it separated by comma?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have missed the enabledelayedexpansion keyword, combined with the regular expression syntax, you would have wiped everything. In essence, you were searching for ^[character set]*$ - e.g. most, if not all lines.

You actually have no need for regular expressions with what you're trying to do.

You can exclude multiple strings with multiple /v statements.

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

rem They can enter a comma separated list of strings to replace
for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%a in (c:\files.txt) do (
    set /p line=ENTER THE LINE YOU WANT TO DISREGARD for %%a:
    set line=!line:,=" /c:"!
    findstr /v /i /c:"!line!" "c:\%%b" > "c:\file1\%%b"
    findstr /v /i /c:"!line!" "c:\%%c" > "c:\file2\%%c"
)
```

Comment: I tried to use you suggestion but no luck. The contents of those files were deleted too

Comment: Are you putting the content into a bat file and running that? e.g. doReplace.bat

Comment: Here's the step regarding my code

1st - files.txt contains filenames of files that can be found on the same directory where files.txt are located. Then I want to remove specific lines for files in column 2 and 3 of files.txt (same as my sample above) then save it. I tried the code you suggested by it still deletes the content of both file for column 2  and column3

Comment: I think you're stating that c:\ has files.txt, Name1.txt, Name2.txt, Age1.txt, Age2.txt, etc. Then given user input, this should alter file1\Name1.txt, file1\Age1.txt, file1\Add1.txt and also alter the file2\* files. I'll update my example to work that way.

Comment: Files.txt contains file names. One I run the batch file I want to open those file names indicated in files.txt and remove user defined to remove the unwanted lines. I think the code above basically creating a files based on the file names indicated in files.txt. I want to implement a batch script that opens files indicated in files.txt and remove user difined start of the line.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem

```
    Set /p line= enter line to remove :
for /f "tokens=2,3" %%a in ('type c:\file\files.txt') do (

Type c:\file\aaa\%%a  | findstr /I /V /C:"!line!" > c:\file\aaa\OUTPUT\%%a 
Type c:\file\bbb\%%b  | findstr /I /V /C:"!line!" > c:\file\bbb\OUTPUT\%%b
```